# Add span for each line break of a paragraph

Tags: javascript, animation, text, split

I am having some trouble to add a span to each line of a paragraph. I want to do that to animate my text like the SplitText plugin from GSAP.

I have looked up for a way and this works fine for each letter of my paragraph :

```
    var regex = /([^\x00-\x80]|\w)/g
    var textWrapper = document.querySelector(
      ".developpement-description .lines"
    );
    textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(
      regex,
      "<span class='letter'>$&</span>"
    );
```

So I thought that by changing the regex to match a linebreak it will work :

```
var regex = /[\n\r]\w/g;
```

But it doesn't...

Could someone help me ?

Comment: `/m` flag? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags_2 `m Multi-line search.`

Answer (score 0):

Try change your regex like below

```
var regex = /[\n\r]/gm;
```

Comment: Nope :/ it doesn't change anything

Comment: Can you please post the content of -> document.querySelector(".developpement-description .lines");

Comment: It gets a JSON file with this string in it : 

Voici les différents projets sur lesquels j’ai travaillé en tant que développeur. Il s’agit pour beaucoup d’entre eux de travaux d’écoles que j’ai réalisé il y a plusieurs années. Mon niveau à beaucoup changé en très peu de temps mais je souhaite les présenter car ils sont important pour moi et ont été des éléments clés dans mon évolution vers la personne que je souhaite devenir demain.